# Does blackberry enterprise server work with simple pop3 accounts?

Tags: bes

I run merak mail server using pop3 and wanted to look into setting up blackberry enterprise server express. Will this work with simple pop3 accounts? If all your calendars are stored locally in outlook how does that work with BES? Thanks. I have a feeling I need to get a different mail server to really get all the features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, BES works with Exchange Server and Domino.

If you wanted to turn your question around - how to use Blackberries with your current mail server - it's possible to use [Blackberry Desktop Software](http://us.blackberry.com/apps-software/desktop/desktop_pc.jsp) to sync the Blackberries locally with Outlook (or some other personal information managers) for calendars, contacts, etc.  Then you either set up forwarding from your mail server to the email address the cell provider sets up with your Blackberry, or some other kludge-y thing like that.

Answer (score 1):

No. BES and BESX work with the Microsoft Exchange Server and IBM Lotus Domino email server platforms.